Which config file is used by w3wp.exe process in an application?
I have a issue where I get SerializationException The internal array cannot expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements..
The solution to this is adding the below line in the config file.
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Runtime.Serialization.UseNewMaxArraySize=true" />

But the problem is even after adding this in web.config file the issue is not getting resolved.
.Net version is 4.8 and also restarted the IIS after making changes.
I have used procmon to see the config file used by the w3wp, it shows the config file path as:
For some process: C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\Archer\Archer.config
For some other process: C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.config
Please help me to know which configuration file is used by the w3wp.exe process as it got reported that particular process.
Here is the stack trace:
<InnerException>
    <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
    <Message>Unable to find html field value for typename 'Field'</Message>
    <Source>CompanyTech.Notifications</Source>
    <StackTrace>  at CompanyTech.Notifications.xslt.NotificationXslExtensions.LookupValue(XPathNodeIterator lookupDefinition, XPathNodeIterator objectIdXPath, String pluginPrefix)</StackTrace>
    <InnerException>
        <ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
        <Message>The internal array cannot expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements.</Message>
        <Source>mscorlib</Source>
        <StackTrace>  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.Rehash()

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator.GetId(Object obj, Boolean&amp; firstTime)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.InternalGetId(Object obj, Boolean assignUniqueIdToValueType, Type type, Boolean&amp; isNew)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Schedule(Object obj, Boolean assignUniqueIdToValueType, Type type, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMembers(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo memberTypeNameInfo, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMemberSetup(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String memberName, Type memberType, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String[] memberNames, Type[] memberTypes, Object[] memberData, WriteObjectInfo[] memberObjectInfos)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)

  at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)

  at CompanyTech.Notifications.ContentRender.LevelRecordDataContainerDeepCopy(LevelRecordDataContainer levelRecordDataContainer)

  at CompanyTech.Notifications.ContentRender..ctor(IRenderEngine engine, Content content, LevelRecordDataContainer levelRecordDataContainer)

  at CompanyTech.Notifications.Rendering.RenderEngine.GetFieldHtml(Int32 contentId, Int32 fieldId)

  at CompanyTech.Notifications.Providers.Value.ArcherContentNotificationValueProvider.GetHtmlReplacement(String objectId, ValuePlaceholder valuePlaceholder)

  at CompanyTech.Notifications.xslt.NotificationXslExtensions.LookupValue(XPathNodeIterator lookupDefinition, XPathNodeIterator objectIdXPath, String pluginPrefix)</StackTrace>
    </InnerException>
</InnerException>


What serializer? I doubt that its an actual case of Array to small. StackTrace of the error might also help to point us in the right direction.

@Ralf Its a binary formatter serializer. I have added the stack trace above. I don't want to use any other formatter. I had a issue with other process as well. As I was aware of the config file used by that process, it worked well there. But here I am stuck as I am not very sure about the config file used by w3wp.exe.

According to the answers in this thread, you need to add <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Runtime.Serialization.UseNewMaxArraySize=true" /> into App.Config.

After adding the below line in the Web.Config the issue got resolved.
<appSettings>
    <add key= "AppContext.SetSwitch:Switch.System.Runtime.Serialization.UseNewMaxArraySize" value = "True"/>
</appSettings>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
